# Getting "null" (as String) programatically in Java?

Tags: java, string, casting

Is there any way to get "null" as String programatically in Java?

I've been investigating, but didn't find a way. I would like to do something like:

```
String nullValue = <XXX>//where XXX returns "null"
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Ummm,what about `"null"`?

Comment: `String nullValue = "null"`? What exactly do you need? String can either be null or a sequence of characters, and `"null"` is a sequence of characters.

Comment: you can do this..  `nullValue + ""`

Comment: I suspect that you're later checking for that special String. I think this is a bad Idea since it pretty much implies the "Status return value" antipattern. Java has Exceptions to signal error conditions. Don't abuse "special values" to inform the caller about errors.

Comment: @piet.t I want to get it programmatically. Please read the question

Comment: @stackman What do you mean by "programmatically"? If `"null"` is not "programtically" is `"n"+"ull"`? Is a function using `"return null"`? VTC as unclear what you are asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a null value, you should use the implicit `null` literal.

```
String nullValue = null;
```

If you need a String equivalent of it, you can use this:

```
String nullString = null;
String nullValue = String.valueOf(nullString);
```

Comment: I updated the answer. The NPE is thrown because it is using the `String.valueOf(char[] data);` overload.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're after, but if it's any help - `String.valueOf(Object)` will return string `"null"` for `null` input.

```
    public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
        return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
    }
```

Note that some other overloads of `String.valueOf` throw `NullPointerException` if given null input.

Comment: And here I thought the whole reason to use String.valueOf instead of toString was to avoid NPE. Another dream shattered.